# Hatcher's terminology

Tags: algebraic-topology

Hatcher uses the words "path-component" and "component" without giving their definition. The first occurrence of "path-component" is on p. 19, exercise 12. The first occurrence of "component" is on p. 6, example 0.2.

I think "path-component" means "path-connected component". But what is a "component" of a topological space? He seems to use it to mean a $k$-cell, for any $k$. Is this the definition?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think it just means "connected component" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hatcher just means connected components. It is assumed that if you are reading Hatcher you have some background in general topology.